# Running Batch File Using Java ProcessBuilder does not recognized Network drive

Tags: java, spring-boot, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a java program (jar) that uses ProcessBuilder to execute a dynamic batch file.

```
Process process = (new ProcessBuilder(commands)).start();
```

I have a simple batch file like this, Z --> is a network drive. let say my batch file location is in my_batch.bat.

```
copy Z:\Download\*.csv D:\Download\
```

if I execute this batch file from the command prompt, it run successfully. But if I execute using the java program, the program does not work (nothing happen). But if I change the batch file like below, it works. E-> is a regular drive (not a network drive).

```
copy E:\Download\*.csv D:\Download\
```

I don't know why this can happen, please help.
My Operating System is Windows.

Comment: Network drive mapping is done for specific user only. Add to your batch command `whoami & pause` run it both ways and compare output.

Comment: Yes, you're right the batch file executed from the java program is "nt authority\system" and if I run the batch file manually the result of whoami is  "my_domain\administrator", so how to run my program not as "nt authority\system" but as administrator instead, or give the access also to the "nt authority\system" ?

Comment: Hi @user2956477, now I can change the java program to run as user administrator, because my java program run as a service, and now whoami shows the same user which is "my_domain\administrator" but still I cannot make it works.

Comment: try to add `net use` into your batch and check if script see drive Z: as mapped. If yes, add `dir z:` and check output. If work fine, than problem is probaby seomewhere else.

Comment: from java program, it shows the Z drive, but the status is unavailable, if I run the batch manually, it shows the Z drive and the status is OK.

Comment: Get psexec tool if you actually dont have it. Start `cmd.exe` as Administrator. Run `psexec -i -s cmd.exe`. Perform `net use z: \\servername\sharedfolder /persistent:yes`. Than close all console windows and check your start script again.

Comment: thanks for your help, now I already solved. Yes, I put the net use Z: \\computer\sharedfolder user pasword command in my batch file, and it's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by putting this line in my batch file.

```
net use Z: \\Computer\shared /user:DOMAIN\username password
```

and after the process, use this at the end of my batch file.

```
net use Z: /d
```

thanks to the man that help me in the comment section.